# React multiple routes using the same component but with different parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I have one `Login` component with multiple states, depending on the url I'd like to display different elements within this component. Here is how I've set up my `Routes`

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

// Pages

import Home from '../pages/home';
import Login from '../pages/login';


export default function App() {
  
  // Render
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login state="login"/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/signup" element={<Login state="signup"/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/reset-password" element={<Login state="reset"/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
  
}
```

I'm using BrowserRouter v6 and this code is working fine whenever I load / reload the page. However using a `<Link to="/reset-password"></Link>` to go to from one `Login` page to another does not appear to remount the components on the page.

I have seen some exemples using `<Route exact path="/login" component={...}/>` with BrowserRouter v5 but I can't seem to get it to display anything when using `component` instead of `element` with this version.

I there something I'm missing or am I going about this all wrong ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-routing-issue-the-sloth-hlshbb

Please check the sandbox example. Your code seems to work just fine.

Comment: hmm ok thanks for the lead. I think I've found the problem, it's obviously not coming from the Routes as you have demonstrated. I have some conditional rendering within the Login page which appears to be causing the bug.

Comment: No prob. Yeah issue must be caused by something else.

Answer (score 0):

One new feature from v6 is the new Outlet component. See if creating a layout with an outlet can help you: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/basic

Answer (score 0):

i was having this type of problem.
i had a table as a child component into a parent components of two different routes with different filters.
Async call for data was into parent component and it was being set to redux store.
table was getting data from that store.

problem was that,when i switch between these two routes,it was getting a delay to update data in table.

so i fixed problem by clearing redux state on unmount of child componant (table).
like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    return ()=>{
       // cancel previous API calls that are being used to list data
      //clear data from redux store
    }
  },[dispatch])
```

here the point to be noted that this code should be written **in child component**

(in my case Table).